# Django South Postgres Datamigration Issue

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I'm adding a new model, running a schemamigration. Then adding data to that table with a datamigration. I'm running this on a Postgres db. I've run it successfully on a SQLite db locally, so I'm guessing it's a db-specific issue. The error that comes up in the datamigration is:

```
Error in migration: app:0109_add_reservation_rates
DatabaseError: column "rate_currency" specified more than once
LINE 1: ...rate_currency", "rate", "reservation_id", "date", "rate_curr...
                                                             ^
```

There is no better error that South gives me and I haven't found a way to produce the SQL that South is supposed to be running. I've checked the schemamigration, datamigration and there is no repeated field name...

Here are the actual migrations:
0108_etc...py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding model 'ReservationRate'
        db.create_table(u'app_reservationrate', (
            (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('created_on', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)),
            ('updated_on', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now=True, blank=True)),
            ('reservation', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(related_name='reservation_rates', to=orm['app.Reservation'])),
            ('room', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(related_name='reservation_rates', to=orm['app.Room'])),
            ('date', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateField')(db_index=True)),
            ('rate_currency', self.gf('djmoney.models.fields.CurrencyField')(default='USD')),
            ('rate', self.gf('djmoney.models.fields.MoneyField')(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')),
        ))
        db.send_create_signal(u'app', ['ReservationRate'])

        # Adding unique constraint on 'ReservationRate', fields ['reservation', 'room', 'date']
        db.create_unique(u'app_reservationrate', ['reservation_id', 'room_id', 'date'])
```

0109_etc...py

```
coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        for reservation in orm.Reservation.objects.all():
            # Loop through some code, get rates, and dates for creating ReservationRate objects...
            orm.ReservationRate.objects.create(reservation=reservation, room=stay.room, date=date, rate=rate)
```

Anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: It is not database specific. It clearly states that `rate_currency` is present twice

Comment: It's not though. Adding the actual migration snippets to the question now.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure why, but running `./manage.py migrate -v2 app` made everything work correctly. I believe that option is supposed to run the migration and output more info on what it's running.